# any way to update parent variable when updating its alias?

Tags: python, variables, reference, alias

How to update the parent variable when updating its alias?

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
parent = 3
alias = parent
alias = 4 
print(parent)
=====
the result is 3.
but the expected is 4.
```

Comment: You are not updating the "alias", you are replacing it. And that's pretty much the only thing you can do with immutable objects like `int`s.

Comment: For newcomers, mutable objects include: list, dictionary, set; immutable objects include: integer, float, tuple, boolean, string, frozenset.